# how to align/hide/show div ( position: fixed) within in a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have HTML page with some CSS, such that in a container div with position set to relative, I have a main content div and overlay div, overlay div has position fixed such that it is displayed 10px above the bottom of the screen(viewport). How can make sure it also appears horizontally centered inside the main content div, also how to hide it such that when user scrolls to the bottom , it doesn't appear in the footer area and may be reappear when user scrolls back up to the content area. can this be done with just css or with javascript?

```html
<div id="header">
  <p>Header</p>
</div>

<div id="container" style="position:relative">
  <div id="leftMenu">
  </div>

  <div id="content" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
    <p>Main content</p>
  </div>

  <div id="overlay" style="height:50px; width:450px; bottom:10px; position:fixed">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done with css

```css
#container {
  height: 150vh;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

#overlay {
  background: blue;
  opacity: .5;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#footer {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <p>Header</p>
</div>

<div id="container" style="position:relative">
  <div id="leftMenu">
  </div>

  <div id="content" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
    <p>Main content</p>

  </div>
  <div id="overlay" style="height:50px; width:450px; bottom:10px; position:fixed">
  </div>

</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks . I will open a new question if needed. one thing that just occurred to me was , one another possible use case , i have is , if user clicks anywhere in the page, I might need to close this div.

Comment: That will require some js but that is not so hard I'm sure that if you look on google for a minute you can figure it out. If not, just ask a new question on SO :)

Comment: thanks again. one other thing , i noticed was. in my overlay div i have a button. I noticed that when i scroll the main content and when the overlay is on top of the main content area , the button is unclickable, only when i scroll enough and the overlay is towards the end of the main content. i can click the button. how do we handle such sitatuations , where another div is right on top of bigger div and there is a button we want to click.